# How do I verify that the form input date is valid?

Tags: 8, datetime

Some browsers (e.g. Safari) allow rubbish dates to slip through a form `Date` field so that  we get a fatal PHP error  (`Call to a member function format() on null`) when we invoke the `DrupalDateTime::format()` per the code below which doesn't catch any exception.

The user can type `19-00` into the time part of the date field instead of `19:00:00` and this will cause Drupal 8.0.5 to crash.

What is the correct way to test that a date in a `DrupalDateTime` object in the form array can be formatted properly? This doesn't work (snippet from an `entity_builder` for new and changed *Meeting* Nodes in our *Meeting* module):

```
try {
    $formatted_date_of_meeting = $date_of_meeting->format('l, j F Y');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $form_state->setError($form, $e->getMessage());
}
$node->setTitle($name_of_meeting.' on '.$formatted_date_of_meeting);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is valid, then the form state will return an object of type `Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime`, and otherwise it will return an array with the invalid values. Since the invalid date format will be caught elsewhere, the custom code need only check if the value is an instance of `DrupalDateTime`:

```
if ($date_of_meeting instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
  $formatted_date_of_meeting = $date_of_meeting->format('l, j F Y');
  $node->setTitle($name_of_meeting.' on '.$formatted_date_of_meeting);
}
```